# Amazon RDS Mysql Databse with TLS 1.2 and ASP.NET Application

Tags: mysql, asp.net, amazon-web-services, tls1.2

We are trying to access our MySql RDS instance which is tls1.2 enabled. Our AWS asp.net application server also has tls1.2 protocol enabled. But Application is not able to make connection to database with the error. 
We have tried with enabling various Ciphers and also applying .pem files with asp.net connection string. But still can not connect to it. However no connection string is working out for us.

**Error: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.**

[image: Connection strings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few changes in the server cipher settings we are now able to connect to the RDS instance using our C# console application (mysql connector latest version)
Below are the findings :

1. application level (code) changes : None
2. Server Crypto settings ( using Nartac ) : Best Practices
3. machine (currently tested from DB server to RDS instance ) TLS version : v1.2 enforced
4. RDS TLS version : v1.2 enforced

[image]

[image]

My connection string :

```
**<add key="conns" value="SERVER=asdf.asdfasdfa.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;database=FFF;user=FFFF;PASSWORD=p@5sword;SslMode=REQUIRED;"/>**
```

Output :  connection successful